# How to rewrite this pseudo-class selector in JS to work in Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class

I have this seudo-class selector in a script:

```
querySelectorAll("header:has(+ div.content)");
```

When I display the page in Firefox, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelectorAll: 'header:has(+div.content)' is not a valid selector
```

The same script works fine in Chromium-like browsers.

I wrote an alternative script to make it work in Firefox, but I would like to know if it is possible to rewrite de selector to have just one script instead both.

Thanks in advance

PD:

1. You can get the page in JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n0kr7to4/3/)
2. I am aware of the existance of details tag

Comment: See the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility) table. To use it in Firefox you need to enable the `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` preference.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to use the following selector: `div.content ~ header`? (The sibling selector...) It seems there'll be only one header...

Comment: @Pieterjan A sibling is not the same as a descendant.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently the pseudoclass `:has()` in the DOM Selectors API is still not widely [supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has) in browsers and other environments (JSDOM, etc.).

**If performance is not important**, you can try using [polyfill-pseudoclass-has](https://github.com/olegbarabanov/polyfill-pseudoclass-has) to add support for the pseudoclass `:has()` in the methods `.querySelector()`,`.querySelectorAll()`, `.matches()`, `.closest()`.

Below is your example, but with added polyfill:

```js
const headers = document.querySelectorAll("header:has(+ div.content)");
for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  const header = headers[i];
  header.addEventListener("click", () => {
    header.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Adds a polyfill for :has() -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/polyfill-pseudoclass-has@0.0.4/dist/polyfill.umd.js" onload="window['polyfill-pseudoclass-has'].addToBrowser();"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <header>Level 1</header>
  <div class="content hidden">
    1111 1111 1111 1111

    <header>Level 2</header>
    <div class="content hidden">
      2222 2222 2222 2222

      <header>Level 3</header>
      <div class="content hidden">
        3333 3333 3333 3333

        <header>Level 4</header>
        <div class="content hidden">
          4444 4444 4444 4444

          <header>Level 5</header>
          <div class="content hidden">
            5555 5555 5555 5555
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```